# back to back infiniband

Tags: storage-area-network, hba, infiniband

I've been given two hpc cluster nodes, each with an infiniband hca.

Is it possible to connect them back-to-back, without using a switch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not a problem at all. You will still need a subnet manager running on one of them(like OSM from the OFED stack).

Comment: aptitude gave me `opensm` : Infiniband subnet manager. I guess this is what you call OSM right ?

Comment: opensm is the subnet manager from the open fabrics enterprise distribution ib stack.